# setting VCCLCompilerTool.TreatWChar_tAsBuiltInType property on MSBuild command line

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I need to build Visual Studio 2010 projects with `wchar_t` **not** being native type. The IDE setting should be equal to the value of [`VCCLCompilerTool.TreatWChar_tAsBuiltInType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcclcompilertool.treatwchar_tasbuiltintype%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property. However trying to set it using `/p:VCCLCompilerTool.TreatWChar_tAsBuiltInType=false` on MSBuild command seems to fail. Is there any other way how I could achieve this from the MSBuild command line?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set environment variable CL to /Zc:wchar_t-

Example batch file to compile with forced /Zc:wchar_t-:

`set CL=/Zc:wchar_t-`

```
%windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe projectName.vcxproj /t:Rebuild
```